# Liferay.Language.get("key") is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Language.get("key") for getting value from properties file in JavaScript ,But its not working .If any other solution for getting value from properties file in JavaScript please tell me I am using Liferay 6.2 .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title and the actual question mention different calls. Apparently `Language.get("key")` does not work on portlet level, so that might be the reason why it's not working. `Liferay.Language.get('key');` should do the trick.